# Divide data into multiple groups as similar as possible

Tags: r, random, partitioning, sampling

I have a data frame in the format

```
> head(daten_strat)
   id age gender anxiety
1   7  40      2       7
2   3  53      1       8
3   4  40      1       4
4   1  62      2       8
5   5  60      2      11
6   6  45      1       8
```

I would like to create 4 random groups that are as similar as possible in terms of the distribution of gender, age and anxiety.

In a university course, we plan an intervention with 4 different conditions. In order to assign the participants to the 4 conditions, I would like to use R to perform a stratified randomization. As a final result, I would like to have 4 groups as similar as possible in terms of age, gender, and level of anxiety. So that (somewhat simplified) differences in effectiveness cannot be attributed to demographic differences between the groups.

Comment: Maybe you want to run a cluster analysis like a kmeans based on those 3 variables to create the 4 groups.

Comment: What is your goal? But if you state that, maybe your resulting question would better belong on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would not call this task stratified sampling, you are not trying to get a representative sample of a population. What you are looking to do is partitioning. The [`anticlust` package](https://github.com/m-Py/anticlust) with its `anticlustering()` function provides a number of methods for this task. I'll show a basic example with defaults below. You might want to look into the methods more deeply if you want to use the partitioning for research purposes.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(anticlust)
set.seed(42)

# Example data
dat <- tibble(
  id = as.character(1:100),
  age = rnorm(100, 50, 10) |> round(),
  gender = sample(1:2, 100, T),
  anxiety = rnorm(100, 7.5, 2.25) |> round()
)

dat <- dat |> 
  mutate(group = anticlustering(dat[, -1], K = 4)) # Basic usage with defaults 
dat
#> # A tibble: 100 × 5
#>    id      age gender anxiety group
#>    <chr> <dbl>  <int>   <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1        64      2       7     2
#>  2 2        44      2       4     1
#>  3 3        54      1      10     4
#>  4 4        56      2       7     3
#>  5 5        54      1       6     3
#>  6 6        49      1       5     3
#>  7 7        65      2       7     3
#>  8 8        49      2       6     2
#>  9 9        70      2       6     1
#> 10 10       49      2      10     2
#> # … with 90 more rows
```

As you can see below, the between-group variance for all variables is fairly low.

```r
# Means across groups
dat |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  summarize(across(age:anxiety, mean))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   group   age gender anxiety
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1  50.3   1.48    7.48
#> 2     2  50.2   1.44    7.52
#> 3     3  50.5   1.44    7.4 
#> 4     4  50.2   1.44    7.44
```